# Deploying custom image on PXE client by WDS gives me 0c0000428 error

Tags: deployment, pxe-boot, wds

I create a reference VM, configure and install required programs and do sysprep.

I capture an image by WDS (capture image) and upload it on WDS Server.

When i try to deploy the image on PXE clients (which is a VM too), it boots WinPE, installs windows and when it's done I get this error from "Windows Boot Manager":

```
File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
Status: 0xc0000428
Info: Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file.
```

Did I miss something when i was imaging the reference system ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Bootmanager is missing or corrupt and most likely due to having the wrong deployment tools installed. Deployment tool kit contains tools to create bootmanager.

1. For Server 2012 & Windows 8 - **install WADK**

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh825486.aspx)

2. For server 2008 and Windows 7  - **install WAIK**

(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349350(WS.10).aspx)

Having the correct toolkit will ensure the correct bootmanager is deployed.